# Visual Studio 2013 devenv.exe crashes randomly on TFS activities

Tags: visual-studio-2013, version-control, tfs

Generally "Source Control Explorer" and "Team Explorer" windows can be opened but sometimes this windows cause crash independently. If it doesn't I try to get latest version but it crashes after downloading some files.

Non-controlled solutions work fine but if I can try to open a controlled solution VS crashes on loading solution.

This problem started today. I use Windows 10 but migrated from Windows 8.1 a couple of months ago. In this morning windows session could not start when I've entered my password to windows login screen. So I've resetted my computer by clicking reset button. But Windows 10 re-run its migration tool and I think that it repaired some applications. I checked the Programs and Features out then a lot of apps seems installed today.

Repaired my VS install from Programs and Features but it didn't solve. Tried WinThruster, it found issues over 1000 but it didn't solved, too.

VS adds these three logs together to event viewer when app crashes.

**Error:**

```
Fault bucket 128975310163, type 5
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: devenv.exe
P2: 12.0.40629.0
P3: 5590c8a4
P4: mscorlib
P5: 4.6.1038.0
P6: 5615c1ac
P7: 3b10
P8: 7
P9: System.InvalidProgramException
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\Onur\AppData\Local\Temp\WERF382.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
C:\Windows\Temp\WERFF3A.tmp.csv
C:\Users\Onur\AppData\Local\Temp\WERFF3B.tmp.appcompat.txt
C:\Users\Onur\AppData\Local\Temp\WERA2A.tmp.WERDataCollectionFailure.txt

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_devenv.exe_d949c0dbc7d16a4f9e0b0cdb431782229fc6a1_5b0449f2_1c961310

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 1b1069cb-61a5-4133-881d-e3ae5b11ae68
Report Status: 4105
Karma demeti (*): 944bc6d8e7edc70b70df076898124c29
```

(*) I translated from turkish but couldn't find the english equivalent of "Karma demeti" after googling. Maybe it can be "Mixed bucket".

**Error:**

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidProgramException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.QueuedActionLimiter.DeliverAction(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

**Info:**

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 12.0.40629.0, time stamp: 0x5590c8a4
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.10586.0, time stamp: 0x5632da1c
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000bd8a8
Faulting process id: 0x1ae4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d13672bb0a871a
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you use the VS2013 Update 5?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Did you try to open a version-controlled file on another client machine?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT TFS version was not changed. Everyone instead of me still ok.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have upgraded both your TFS and VS to the latest edition of its version.

Then check whether you can reproduce this issue on another client machine, if the issue only occurs on your client machine, you can try resetting VS settings and add-in settings (`devenv /ResetSettings`) and (`devenv /ResetSkipPkgs`), try rebuilding all templates (`devenv /setup`).

Comment: As your issue is randomly, and only your client machine has this issue. If resetting devenv can't solve the issue, maybe some software on your machine cause this error. Let's see whether the issue will disappear after reinstalling windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you already use the lasted Update, Update 5, you should [report this crash on connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/). You should also provide a crash dump. To do this you can configure [Windows Error Reporting to generate dumps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx) or install [Procdump](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) as post Mortem Debugger by running `procdump -ma -i C:\dumps`. Now repo your crash and if you got a dump, zip the dmp and attach it to the report.